# How to design separate UIView outside of any ViewController in Storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiview, uiscrollview

I would like to design a UIView, which is larger than a ViewController in Storyboard (iOS 5).

The UIView should be used as the subview of a UIScrollView and hence be larger than any of my existing ViewControllers. How can I create such a UIView in Storyboard and associate it with my UIScrollView?

I would like to do this without xib files if possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Tricky problem, this was so easy before the age of storyboards.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see no other option than using xibs, but it's not that annoying:

```
//We have file called "View.xib" in our project. It contains one SINGLE view
NSArray *xibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *view = [xibContents lastObject]; //safer than objectAtIndex:0

[self.scrollview addSubview:view];
self.scrollview.contentSize = view.frame.size;
```

In order to make IB connections you can set the `filesOwner` class in the xib to be your viewController, and connect like usual.

Comment: You may want to have a look at my related question/answer, regarding the design decisions that may justify that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386111/uiview-outside-of-a-view-controller-in-a-storyboard

Comment: Clean and super fast solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: Added stand alone .xib file not working for auto layout. Though whole project is with auto layout. How i apply auto layout with this .xib file?

Answer (score 2):

You can place a `UIView` into your scrollview and directly design it inside the `viewController` of your `scrollView`

Comment: Hi Ugur, my UIView is larger than the ScrollView, so the majority of controls would be outside the currently visible area.

Comment: Than xibs may be the only solution to design it in an interface builder

Answer (score 1):

I've found the way to edit the view added to the scene (being at the same hierarchy level  as ViewController).

Unfortunately it is from `hackish` types of actions.
My `Xcode` version is `Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)`. I've tested this in real project and new empty project.

The basic idea is that `Xcode` do have an ability to edit such external views, unfortunately this mode doesn't activate straightforwardly.

In the method that I've found you need to have 2 levels of hierarchy inside your external view:

```
Scene
|- VC
   |- View
|- ExternalView
   |- SubView1
      |- SubView2
```

- Then goto `Document Outline` panel
- find `SubView2` in the tree of your scene
- double click it

The editing area will appear and its coordinates will be saved to project's user data, so you can move it to more suitable place if you want to, and next time you'll open the storyboard in IB on the machine it will be there. Although I think on other machines you'll have to do it again (I haven't tested that).